# Random freezing in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: freeze

I have done several fresh installs, but my Intel NUC 11 freezes while doing random work. Today at 11;16 AM it froze while moving some pictures to trash from Shotwell. I have checked the file system from gparted, checked memory, and did a CPU stress test. My NVMe SSD does not have smart capability. CPU is Intel Pentium Silver N6005 and 16GB RAM. When it happens, only hard resetting the device and booting up again gets me up and running until the next freeze. I am fairly new to Linux and do not understand what the messages in the log means. Any feedback will be much appreciated.

**Summary of log before the freeze:**

09:57:41 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

09:57:36 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

09:57:35 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

09:57:13 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

09:57:12 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

09:57:11 kernel: spi-nor spi0.0: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: c2 75 18 c2 75 18

**Summary of log after hard reset:**

11:18:04 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

11:17:59 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

11:17:58 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

11:17:49 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

11:17:48 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

11:17:47 kernel: spi-nor spi0.0: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: c2 75 18 c2 75 18